# htaccess 301 redirect rule with removing specefic text from url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, permalinks

I am trying to redirect my site to the new website by removing specific text from the permalink.

```
Old website: oldsite.com/aamir-khan-bio/ 
new website: newsite.com/aamir-khan/
```

Just need to remove **-bio** using the rewriting rule. I've tried the below code. but it's not working properly.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)\-bio/?$
RewriteRule ^ https://newsite.com/%1/ [R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following htaccess Rules. Please make sure to put this at top of your htaccess rules file. Make sure your new domain is configured properly.

Clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?oldsite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-bio/?$ https://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Comment: @Rashed Hasan, Hi, did this solution worked for you?